# Как в плагине Wordpress подключить datepicker?

Tags: wordpress, datepicker

Плагин подключаю по шорткоду:

```
function ljusers_user_shortcode ($atts, $content = null) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
    wp_register_style( 'jquery-ui', 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui' );
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( '/js/custom-script.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );

    return '<div id="datepicker"></div>';
}
add_shortcode('ljuser', 'ljusers_user_shortcode');
```

**custom-script.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#datepicker" ).html("nggyhfgb")
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
})
```

Вижу, что div с id "datepicker" на странице есть и он заполняется "nggyhfgb", но календарь не появляется.

Поставил зависимости, все-равно не работает:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker', array('jquery-ui') );
    wp_register_style( 'jquery-ui', 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui' );
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( '/js/custom-script.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery', 'jquery-ui') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
```

Вот мой код (корневой файл плагина sgus-quest.php):

```
<?php
function ljusers_user_shortcode ($atts, $content = null) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui', 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );

    wp_register_style( 'jquery-ui', 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui' );

    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( '/js/custom-script.js', __FILE__ ), array(
        'jquery',
        'jquery-ui',
    ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );

    return '<input type="text" id="sgus-datepicker">';
}

add_shortcode('ljuser', 'ljusers_user_shortcode');
```

Comment: Определите зависимости скриптов: ui должен зависеть от jquery, date picker от ui, а custom от них всех.

Comment: Поставил зависимости, все-равно не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде ряд ошибок.

- Зависимости. ui должен зависеть от jquery, а custom - от ui.
- Не запущен сам скрипт ui. Стиль - не скрипт.
- datepicker не работает в div, нужен input.
- $ в вашем скрипте работать не будет, потому что WP запускает jquery в compatibility mode.

Ниже работающий код, который я поместил в шаблоне страницы. Поскольку `plugins_url` тут не работает, я добавил код custom.js непосредственно в шаблон.

Результат можете посмотреть на моём тестовом сайте http://test.kagg.eu/so864820/.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: 864820
*/

get_header();

?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
<?php

function ljusers_user_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui', 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );

    wp_register_style( 'jquery-ui', 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui' );

    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( '/js/custom-script.js', __FILE__ ), array(
        'jquery',
        'jquery-ui',
    ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );

    return '<input type="text" id="datepicker">';
}

add_shortcode( 'ljuser', 'ljusers_user_shortcode' );

echo do_shortcode( '[ljuser]' );

get_footer();
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает (

Comment: Вы же видите - у меня работает. Я вам живой пример дал. Значит, вы что-то делаете не так. Сравнивайте свой код с моим посимвольно.

Comment: Привел свой код.

Comment: Этот код невозможно использовать для проверки. Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve как это сделал я. Выкиньте из плагина все классы, хуки активации и прочее, протестируйте только код datepicker. Сообщите, что именно не работает, какие ошибки в консоли, что выводится и что ожидается. Или используйте мой пример для проверки у себя на сайте.

Comment: Убрал лишние теги. Это стандартный файл плагина, я не знаю, как его можно модифицировать и зачем, если он как раз нужен в этом виде.

Comment: А затем, чтобы вычленить ошибку. Это базовый принцип тестирования. Какие ошибки сейчас в консоли браузера? Что именно не работает?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/p275BLwHoMGo7r

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81206/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-).